# How to display more than 20 pipeline of history in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I use gitlab API to list all pipeline in ci history, using following query

```
curl --insecure -sH "PRIVATE-TOKEN: "${TOKEN}"" GET "https://git.do.x5.ru/api/v4/projects/"${PROJECT_ID}"/pipelines/"
```

But unfortunately it shows only 20 latest pipelines. Is there way to get for example 50 latest pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#pipelines-pagination) :

> By default, GET requests return 20 results at a time because the API
>   results are paginated

Check [Pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#pagination) documentation to know how to increase the number of items listed per page or how to iterate over pages